# C++ constructor parameter as object

Tags: c++, c++11

On compiling the code below I get an error.

```
class shared {
public:
    shared() {
       cout<<"class shared \n";
    }

};

class test1 {      
public:
    test1(shared obj){
        cout<<"class test1 \n";
    }  
};

class test2 {
private:
    shared s_obj;
    test1 test1_obj(s_obj);  // Error statement 
};

int main()
{
    test2 b_obj;
    return 0;
}
```

```
ERROR : error: ‘s_obj’ is not a type
     test1 test1_obj(s_obj);
```

Comment: You cannot define a member variable of a non trivial type in that way: `test1 test1_obj(s_obj);`.

Comment: Use uniform initialization syntax `test1 test1_obj{s_obj};`

Answer (score 4):

You can't initialize your members like that, you should use a member initialization list:

```
class test2
{
    test2() : test1_obj(s_obj) {}
    private:
    shared s_obj;
    test1 test1_obj;
};
```

Or you can use uniform initialization as said in the comments:

```
test1  test1_obj{s_obj};
```

Comment: error: ‘s_obj’ is not a type
     test1 test1_obj(s_obj);
                     ^
In constructor ‘test2::test2()’:
 error: class ‘test2’ does not have any field named ‘test1_obj’
     test2() : test1_obj(s_obj) {}

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
test1 test1_obj(s_obj);
```

is the [most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

In principle `X Y(Z)` could be interpreted either as

1. declaring a variable `Y` of type `X`, initialized with value `Z`, or
2. declaring a function `Y` returning type `X` and taking a single argument of type `Z`.

You wanted #1, but interpretation #2 is actually mandatory.

That is, you want to declare a `test1` object initialized with `s_obj`, but this is actually declares a function called `test1_obj`, which returns `test1` and takes a single argument of type `s_obj` (as the error states, no such type exists).

This is one of the reasons for using uniform initialization:

```
test1 test1_obj{s_obj};
```

isn't ambiguous because it can't be mistaken for a function.